# How to change attribute of the table row, which is foreign key of the table saved by event 'after_insert' in SQLAlchemy

Tags: events, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

As in the example. When the new KlocworkViolation is inserted i want to change the it's foreign key table attribute to proper count of related KlocworkViolation objects.

```
class KlocworkViolation(db.Model):

     metrics_id = Column(ForeignKey("metrics.id"))
     metrics = relationship("Metrics", backref=backref("klockworkviolation", uselist=False))

class Metrics(db.Model):
     ...
     klocwork_count = Column(SmallInteger, info={'verbose_name': 'Klocwork Violations', })
     ...
```

Here's the event hook

```
@listens_for(KlocworkViolation, 'after_insert')
def count_kw(mapper, connection, target):
     count = db.session.query(KlocworkViolation).filter_by(metrics_id=target.metrics_id).count()
     print target.metrics # returns None
     print target.metrics_id # returns None
     target.metrics.klocwork_count=count
```

It seems, that I cannot access the foreign key at this point.

Comment: Do you really have a strong preference to storing this redundantly instead of just counting when you need it?

Comment: The data is fetched to database but I need to know in some way whether the data was fetched or not (then klocwork_count==None)